# Closed form of, or series for $\int_{\epsilon-i\infty}^{\epsilon+i\infty}\frac{e^{az+b^2z^2}}{\sin\pi z}\,dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function

I've been trying to find a closed form expression/series expansion for the following integral without success:

$$F(a,b)=\int_{\epsilon-i\infty}^{\epsilon+i\infty} e^{az+b^2z^2}\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)\,dz=\pi\int_{\epsilon-i\infty}^{\epsilon+i\infty}\frac{e^{az+b^2z^2}}{\sin\pi z}\,dz$$

for some $\epsilon\in(0,1)$. Any input is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Asymptotic expansion as $\epsilon\to 0$?

Comment: $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{1}{\sin\pi z}$ so the poles of the integrand are the integers. This implies that the integral is the same for $0<\epsilon<1$.

Comment: Good point, but since you mentioned asymptotic expansion, it is natural to as: is it an expansion for small $a,b$, large $a,b$ or something else?

Comment: What I really meant was to find a closed form expression or a series expansion for the integral. Sorry about the confusion!

Comment: @metamorphy: I wouldn't mind if you write it down here for the record ;)

Comment: @Diger: Done (in a very short manner, just a reference and a few words).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrals of this type are systematically studied by [L. J. Mordell](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485888015). One of them is $$I(z,\tau)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\exp(i\pi\tau w^2-2zw)}{\exp(2\pi w)-1}\,dw,\qquad(z,\tau\in\mathbb{C},\ \Im\tau>0)$$ where the path of integration encircles $w=0$ from below (we may assume that it is $\int_{-\infty-i\epsilon}^{\infty-i\epsilon}$ along the straight line), so that our $F(a,b)$ is basically $2\pi I\left(-\frac{\pi+ia}{2},\frac{ib^2}{\pi}\right)$. The relevant result is \begin{align*}
I(z,\tau)&=\color{blue}{\frac{\eta(z/\tau,-1/\tau)+i\tau\eta(z,\tau)}{\tau\theta(z,\tau)}},
\\i\theta(z,\tau)&:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^n q^{(n+1/2)^2}e^{(2n+1)iz},
\\i\eta(z,\tau)&:=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^n\frac{q^{(n+1/2)^2}}{1+q^{2n+1}}e^{(2n+1)iz},
\end{align*} where $q=e^{i\pi\tau}$ (and $q^\alpha$ means $e^{i\pi\tau\alpha}$); the "theta" is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function) as $\theta_1$ or $\vartheta_{11}$ (I'm adhering to the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20.2) notation which seems more common), while the function I've denoted by $\eta$ is in the class of so-called [mock theta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_modular_form). The approach is to obtain functional equations connecting each of $I(z\pm\pi,\tau)$ and $I(z\pm\pi\tau,\tau)$ with $I(z,\tau)$, see that these are satisfied by the proposed result, and finally prove that the solution is unique (similarly to how it's done for elliptic functions, using contour integration of logarithmic derivatives).

> Of course, a naive attempt to use partial fractions for $\pi/\sin\pi z$, resulting in $$F(a,b)=i\pi e^{-c^2}\left(E(-c)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\big(E(nb-c)-E(nb+c)\big)\right),\qquad c=\frac{a}{2b},$$ where $E(z)=e^{z^2}\operatorname{erfc}z=(2/\sqrt\pi)\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2-2zx}\,dx$[${}=E_{1/2}(-z)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function), is possible, but this series, in addition to consisting of "somewhat more special" functions, converges fairly slowly.

Comment: Thanks @metamorphy. I wish I had known this reference earlier, but it might be useful for someone else or for me in the future. You never know :)