# compute $ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{ \cos \pi x }{ e^{2\pi \sqrt{x}} -1 } dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$ \int_0^{\infty} \frac{ \cos \pi x }{ e^{2\pi \sqrt{x}} -1 } dx $$

I guess one common trick is $\frac{1}{1-e^{2\pi \sqrt{x}}} = \frac{1}{1-e^{\pi \sqrt{x}}} + \frac{1}{1+e^{\pi \sqrt{x}}}$ but it doesn't seem to help much?

Comment: This  and many related integrals were discussed by Ramanujan in his paper *Some definite integrals connected with Gauss's sums*, Messenger of Mathematics, XLIV, 1925, pages 75-85.

Comment: Usually one should add context like I did in my previous comment. Questions which are just problem statements (regardless of their challenge factor) are discouraged here. Voting to close.

Comment: As per Ramanujan the value of current integral is $(2-\sqrt{2})/8$.

Comment: There is a typo in my first comment. The paper was published in 1915 instead of 1925. Luckily it is [available online](http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram12.html) now.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh. Thanks for the link. Beautiful paper as everything the Great Ramanujan published. Cheers

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you for sharing this link. Just great!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I admit that even in spite of my best efforts I did not understand much of that particular paper. I can manage Ramanujan theta functions, but his integration techniques are beyond my reach.

Comment: @trancelocation: that website in fact has links to all the published papers of Ramanujan. If you wish you can have a look at http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/html/published_papers.html

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm already there :-).

Comment: Also relevant: a later [work](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485888015) by L. J. Mordell (which I referenced [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3626751)).

Answer (score 4):

For the computation of $$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{ \cos (\pi x) }{ e^{2\pi \sqrt{x}} -1 }\, dx$$ one think we can try is to write the integrand as
$$\frac{ \cos (\pi x) }{ e^{2\pi \sqrt{x}} -1 }=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  e^{-2 \pi  (n+1) \sqrt{x}} \cos (\pi  x)$$ and get in terms of  Fresnel integrals
$$I=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (n+1) \Bigg[2 C\Big[ (n+1)\sqrt{2}\Big]-1\Bigg] $$ which converges rather slowly.

For the partial sums $S_p$ from $n=0$ to $n=p$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  p & S_p \\
 100 & 0.0727242 \\
 200 & 0.0729719 \\
 300 & 0.0730553 \\
 400 & 0.0730971 \\
 500 & 0.0731223 \\
 600 & 0.0731391 \\
 700 & 0.0731511 \\
 800 & 0.0731601 \\
 900 & 0.0731671 \\
 1000 & 0.0731727 \\
\cdots & \cdots \\
\infty & 0.0732233
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: +1 there. You arrived at the correct result. Inverse symbolic calculator should recognize it as $(2-\sqrt{2})/8$.