# Integrating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2) \log(\cosh(x)) dx$ by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gaussian-integral

I need to verify this integration (by parts):
$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)*\log(\cosh(x)) dx\\$

$u=\log(\cosh(x))$ ,then  $du=\tanh(x) dx$

$\\dv=\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2) dx$ ,then $v=1$

using the formula of By parts:$I=uv-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}v du$

$I=\log(\cosh(x))-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tanh(x) dx$

$I=\log(\cosh(x))-\log(\cosh(x))=0$

Comment: Your computation of $v$ is incorrect. The derivative of $1$ is $0$.

Comment: I'm having trouble with how you solved for $v$. What exactly is the antiderivative of $ \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$? As far as I know, the function $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} 
  \exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{\!2}\,\right)$ doesn't have an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Thanks for your reply all,@Accelerator, the integration of the normal distribution from inf to inf is 1

Comment: That is not how integration by parts works

Comment: @ElmarconiAbdo I know, but integration by parts requires you to find an antiderivative for $dv$, not the integral of $dv$ over an interval.

Comment: Are you just trying to find the improper integral? I don't think IBP would work. If you are, then I have an idea of how you can solve it.

Comment: @Accelerator, It would be kind of you to inform me how to solve it

Comment: Sorry, I take that back. At first, I tried using Feynman's Trick, but I ended up circling around (I got too ahead of myself). Another idea I'm trying out is residue theory. Hopefully, these topics aren't too advanced. @ElmarconiAbdo

Comment: Thanks alot for your try, I appreciate your help

Comment: Reduces to [Mordell integrals](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485888015) (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3626751) of mine).