# Any Idea to solve this integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Need help to solve this integration

$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-(x-\mu)^2}\coth(x) dx$

I have tried By parts,

$u=\coth(x)$ ,then $du=1-\coth(x)^2=-(\csc(x))^2$

$dv=xe^{-(x-\mu)^2} dx$ ,then $v=\mu$

using the by parts formula:
$I=uv-\int v du$

$I=\mu \coth(x)+\mu\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\csc(x)^2 dx$

or

$I=\mu \coth(x)-\mu\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1-\coth(x)^2 dx$

Comment: $dv=xe^{-(x-\mu)^2} dx$ then $v=\mu$ ??

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, expectation of x

Comment: I know but, as written, it is not very nice. Then, be more explicit in your statement. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thanks

Comment: Reduces to [Mordell integrals](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485888015) (see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3626751) of mine).